# Set SNS WaitTime in Spring AWS Cloud Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am using [Spring AWS Cloud Framework](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html) to poll for S3 Event notifications on a queue. I am using the `QueueMessagingTemplate` to do this. I want to be able to set the max number of messages and wait time to poll see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;

public class MyQueue {

    private QueueMessagingTemplate queueMsgTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MyQueue(QueueMessagingTemplate queueMsgTemplate) {
        this.queueMsgTemplate = queueMsgTemplate;

    }

    @Override
    public S3EventNotification poll() {
        S3EventNotification s3Event = queueMsgTemplate
            .receiveAndConvert("myQueueName", S3EventNotification.class);
    }
}
```

**Context**

```
@Bean
public AWSCredentialsProviderChain awsCredentialsProviderChain() {
    return new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(
            new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
}

@Bean
public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
    return new ClientConfiguration();
}

@Bean
public AmazonSQS sqsClient(ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration,// UserData userData,
                           AWSCredentialsProviderChain credentialsProvider) {
    AmazonSQSClient amazonSQSClient = new AmazonSQSClient(credentialsProvider, clientConfiguration);
    amazonSQSClient.setEndpoint("http://localhost:9324");
    return amazonSQSClient;
}

@Bean
public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQS sqsClient) {
    return new QueueMessagingTemplate(sqsClient);
}
```

Any idea how to configure these? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QueueMessagingTemplate.receiveAndConvert()` is based on the `QueueMessageChannel.receive()` method where you can find a desired code:

```
@Override
public Message<String> receive() {
    return this.receive(0);
}

@Override
public Message<String> receive(long timeout) {
    ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = this.amazonSqs.receiveMessage(
            new ReceiveMessageRequest(this.queueUrl).
                    withMaxNumberOfMessages(1).
                    withWaitTimeSeconds(Long.valueOf(timeout).intValue()).
                    withAttributeNames(ATTRIBUTE_NAMES).
                    withMessageAttributeNames(MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTE_NAMES));
    if (receiveMessageResult.getMessages().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message amazonMessage = receiveMessageResult.getMessages().get(0);
    Message<String> message = createMessage(amazonMessage);
    this.amazonSqs.deleteMessage(new DeleteMessageRequest(this.queueUrl, amazonMessage.getReceiptHandle()));
    return message;
}
```

So, as you see  `withMaxNumberOfMessages(1)` is hardcoded to `1`. And that is correct because `receive()` can poll only one message. The `withWaitTimeSeconds(Long.valueOf(timeout).intValue())` is fully equals to the provided `timeout`. And eh, you can't modify it in case of `receiveAndConvert()`.

Consider to use `QueueMessageChannel.receive(long timeout)` and `messageConverter` from the `QueueMessagingTemplate`. Like it is done in the:

```
public <T> T receiveAndConvert(QueueMessageChannel destination, Class<T> targetClass) throws MessagingException {
    Message<?> message = destination.receive();
    if (message != null) {
        return (T) getMessageConverter().fromMessage(message, targetClass);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can reach an appropriate `QueueMessageChannel` via code:

```
String physicalResourceId = this.destinationResolver.resolveDestination(destination);
new QueueMessageChannel(this.amazonSqs, physicalResourceId);
```